# Enabling keyboard listener (ctrl+Z) on specific DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to bind the keyboard event ctrl+z through jquery only when a backbone view is rendered and when view is removed, I am unbinding it. But the problem is I want to unbind only the ctrl+z event only for current view.

on Initializing view:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
                if((e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) || (e.which === 89 && e.ctrlKey)){
                    console.log('control + shift + z || control + y');
                    //redoAction;
                }
                else if(e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey){
                    console.log('control + z');
                    //undoAction;
                }          
            });
```

On removing view:

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

But the last statement will unbind all the keyboard listeners. I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a name to your handler function in a declaration (or by assigning it to a variable). Then you can use that name to refer the handler within `.off()`:

```
// Create a named function
function handler (e) {
    if((e.which === 90 ...)
}

// Attach event
$(document).on('keydown', handler);
//Detach event
$(document).off('keydown', handler);
```

Comment: Will this off detach other keydown handlers for $(document) ?

Comment: @vrishank It will remove all keydowns of document, which have `handler` attached as an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "on" handler with a selector and then you can use same selector to unwire events with 'off'. Following is a basic example though not exactly in your problem space, but the concept should be useful to you too.

```
<p id="pOne">Click this paragraph to change its background color.</p>
<button id="btn1">Remove the click event with off()</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#pOne",function(){ //Notice use of "on" here
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    });

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $(document).off('click','#pOne'); 
       //Notice here same selector: #pOne, used with "on"
    });
});
</script>
```

To check the specific event, you can use handler function as last argument similar to other jQuery events.

More from [jQuery 'Off' documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Hope this may help you.

Comment: For click events, its fine. But for keyboard event, in this case, there is no DOM element associated with it on which I can bind the event

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of jQuery's event namespacing feature:

```
// Add multiple listeners under the 'foo' namespace.
$(document).on('keydown.foo', handler1);
$(document).on('keyup.foo', handler2);

// Unbind all listeners at once without keeping reference to the various handlers.
$(document).off('.foo');
```

This is a actually a pattern used by Backbone's View class to easily remove all handlers that are added by the framework to the view's DOM element.